# ionic 3 image slider stops autoplay after manual sliding

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Ionic 3 image slider autoplay works well, but when I slide the image manually the autoplay stops working. Below is my ionic 3 code. I am really stuck here..

```
    slideData = [{ image: "../../assets/img1.jpg" },{ image: "../../assets/img2.jpg" },{ image: "../../assets/img3.jpg" }]
```

html code is as below

```
  <ion-slides  class="slide-css" autoplay="100" loop="true" speed="100" pager="true" autoplayDisableOnInteraction = "false">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slideData">
  <img src="{{slide.image}}" />
  </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Comment: the latest way is to config like this:
const slideOptsFade = {
  speed: 1500,
  autoplay: {
    delay:2000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
https://swiperjs.com/api/#autoplay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone finds a solution for **Ionic 4/5**, to restart the slider after manual sliding just define like this:

```
slideOptsOne = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    autoplay: {
      disableOnInteraction: false
    }
  };
```

HTML:

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOptsOne" color="tertiary">
```

Reference: https://swiperjs.com/api/#autoplay
Cheers

Answer (score 17):

***Update:***

You need to use it like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.slides.autoplayDisableOnInteraction = false;
  }
```

***Note:*** You need to remove `autoplayDisableOnInteraction = "false"` on `html` page.

***Old Answer:***

You can use `autoplayDisableOnInteraction = "false"` as shown below.

```
    <ion-slides  class="slide-css" autoplay="100" loop="true" speed="100" 
                 pager="true" autoplayDisableOnInteraction = "false">

    </ion-slides>
```

[**See how it implements on Ionic**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/slides/slides.ts#L451)

[**Swiper API**](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#autoplay)

> disableOnInteraction  boolean true    Set to false and autoplay will not
>   be disabled after user interactions (swipes), it will be restarted
>   every time after interaction

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware of that attribute. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks! please see the update for more info :) @sebaferreras

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Comment: Actually this doc. works : http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#autoplay

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it is working fine and as expected:

// in your .ts file

```
slideOptsOne = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 3000,
      disableOnInteraction: false
    }

  };
```

And in your HTML -

```
<ion-slides pager="false" [options]="slideOptsOne">
```

**Note:**
I am **NOT even** referencing the slider in my `.ts` file and calling autoplay on `slidesDidLoad` event as follows:

```
slidesDidLoad(slides: IonSlides) {
   slides.startAutoplay();
}
```