# ionic 3 Dynamic image slider stops autoplay after manual sliding

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am taking image slider data from provider rest api. Image Slider works well with autoplay but when after manual sliding, image slider autoplay stops. When ionViewDidEnter() is used then error is generated...

My .ts file is as below

```
    import {Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
    .
    .
    .
    export class DemoPage {
    .
    .
    .
    @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides; 
    .
    .
    .
    allslider: any;
    .
    .
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,public demoapiService: DemoApiProvider)   
    {    
    this.imgSlider();    
    } 

    imgSlider() { 
    this.demoapiService.getImgSlider()  
    .then(myslide => { 
    this.allslider= myslide ;   
    });  
    }

    ionViewDidEnter() 
    {
   // this.slides.autoplayDisableOnInteraction = false;
   // when used above statement then error is generated
    }
```

My .html file as given below

```
    <ion-slides class="slide-css"   #slides *ngIf="allslider && allslider.length" [autoplay]="2000" [speed]="500" [loop]="true" pager>
    <ion-slide   *ngFor="let slide of allslider ">            
    <img src="http://localhost:8000/{{slide.img}}" />
    </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Reference - [ionic 3 image slider stops autoplay after manual sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680612/ionic-3-image-slider-stops-autoplay-after-manual-sliding)

Comment: What is the error? You don't need to give `#slides` here since you imported the `Slides`.

Comment: If i remove #slides and use the ionViewDidEnter() then following error is thrown => core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'autoplayDisableOnInteraction' of undefined
    at DemoPage.webpackJsonp.214.DemoPage.ionViewDidEnter (DemoPage.ts:43)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use it inside the `constructor()` since `DOM` has not been created fully yet.

So you need to remove `this.imgSlider();`

```
 constructor()   
  {    
     //this.imgSlider();<--- need to remove this and use it inside the `ionViewDidEnter()` event.
  }
```

Like so:

```
 ionViewDidEnter() 
    {
      this.imgSlider();
    }

 imgSlider() { 
    this.demoapiService.getImgSlider()  
    .then(myslide => { 
       this.allslider= myslide ;   
       this.slides.autoplayDisableOnInteraction = false;
      });  
    }
```

Comment: Still got error as => Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'autoplayDisableOnInteraction' of undefined

Comment: I followed below approach and succeed... https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-keep-slides-auto-play-when-the-slides-is-swiped/54025/7

Comment: OK, Hope you can put your own answer then no?