# Autoplay not working after leaving the page

Tags: ionic3, angular4-forms

```
 <ion-slides   autoplay="1000" loop="true" speed="100" pager="true" >
            <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of listOfSlides ">
                <img src="{{slide.strImgSource}}" />
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
```

here loop is repeating for the first time and then click on any module method and come back to home page loop is not repeating, displaying only one slide image reaming are not repeated using ionic3 with angular4

Comment: This could be a duplicate of **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680612/ionic-3-image-slider-stops-autoplay-after-manual-sliding)**. Could you please check if that fixes the issue on your end?

Comment: sorry I didn't get ur point may explain somewhat brief

Comment: describe briefly... also provide more code..

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, it is working fine after added this code in my object.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.slides.startAutoplay();
}

ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.slides.update();
    this.slides.autoplayDisableOnInteraction = false;
}

ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.slides.stopAutoplay()
}
```